# how to setup terminator config file to open with multiple tabs

Tags: terminator

I am new with terminator.
I am trying to figure out how to setup a config file that will open one window with multiple tabs.

So far all the config files I have found do  not seem to do anything with tabs.

Does anyone have a simple example of a config file that opens up multiple tabs in a window?

Comment: See if this is useful: https://www.networkworld.com/article/3436784/how-to-use-terminator-on-linux-to-run-multiple-terminals-in-one-window.html

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not using the config, but a script I wrote based on another script I wrote for my job that opens multiple Cluster SSH windows all at once.  One thing I have noticed and that is if you click on the close `X` in the upper right corner of Terminator it leaves the instance open for some reason and the `--new-tab` doesn't quite work properly.  So, you might want to run `sudo pkill terminator` before running the script.  But, if you do type in `exit` into each tab while closing it, it does close properly.

*Every once in a while a terminator hangs on and won't close properly so it opens a single window with errors about key_bindings, but if I run it again it works fine.*

The script:  *You can name it whatever you want.  For now, mine is `term_test.bsh`.*

```
#!/bin/bash

#Kill any previous Terminators.
killall -9 terminator >/dev/null 2>&1

if [[ $1 == "" ]]; then
    echo -n "Please enter number of Terminator tabs you want to open: "
    read num1
else
    num1=$1
fi

if [[ ! ${num1} || ${num1} = *[^0-9]* ]]; then
    echo "${num1} is invalid input.  Please only use numbers."
    exit 1
fi

$(terminator >/dev/null 2>&1 &) && for i in $(seq $((num1-1))); do terminator --new-tab; done
disown -a
```

Example:

```
term_test.bsh 4
```

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: when I ran your script it opened 3 separate windows, not tabs as indicated in your screenshot

Comment: @BarryKimelman  See if the updated script works.

Comment: the updated script seems to be working fine.   thanks.